# Problem while untar a 55GB tar file in solaris

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I created a tar on a solaris box. The result was a 55.2 gb tar file. I used the following command to create the tar archive:

```
tar -Epcvf filename.tar ./directory_name
```

Now the problem is, when i try to untar it with root after entering this command

```
tar -xvf filename.tar
```

I am returned at the command prompt immediately. i.e., no untar happens.

On similar lines, I created another tar of a different directory. This time the tar size was ~15 gb. I did not face any problem untarring this one.

Why would untar fail for the 55gb archive and did not produce any error for 15gb archive?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. gtar was already present in that box. I ran the following command as root,

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gtar -xvf filename.tar
```

But this command did not actually extract any content from the tar. It ran for around half an hour listing the contents of the tar. It did not actually extract. I created the original tar with a simple tar and now I am extracting it with gtar, could this be the reason behind this? If this IS the reason, then is there any way I can extract the content of the tar with a normal tar?

Comment: On what OS are you trying to extract the tar file ?

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use GNU's version of tar ?
If not, please do so, that might solve your problem.
A walktrhough of installation of gnu tar is here : http://sunsolarisadmin.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-install-gnu-tar-in-solaris.html

Comment: I did not use GNU tar. I installed GNU tar with the instructions. It installed tar in /usr/local/bin as tar (should that be gtar instead?). Now when I run /usr/local/bin/tar, i get, ld.so.1: tar: fatal: libintl.so.8: open failed: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The difference to GNU tar should be `-E` (large file support, microseconds) and `-p` (restore files to their original mode). AFAIK the -p is used in combination with `x`, not `c`.
I see two possible problems: lack of rights and symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try star which should be able to automatically read most if not all tar variants.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/star

http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/star.html